# How to search in a huge unix mailbox archive on Windows

Tags: windows, unix, email

I have a standard unix mailbox archive. It is a huge text file, containing tens of thousands of email messages including headers. I would like to search in this file for specific emails on particular topics.

So far I've found a tool named MailNavigator. It allows me to view the emails in the archive, but in the demo version, filtering and searching is only possible in very small archives.
Are there any open source / free alternatives?

The archive is not only of personal interest. Its content is from a specific XML-related Yahoo group. Searching the group pool currently returns nonsense results because, since a few weeks, all XML tags are stripped from the content. Therefore, finding a local solution to this problem is one thing. But a way to convert this content and make it available on a public server again would be even better.

Comment: There's this tool named MailNavigator.  It's not free, but if you  need it, and it works for you, why not pay the $30? :)  Regardless, just asking for a list of software (and/or free alternatives) is considered "not constructive" and "off-topic".

Comment: It's not that simple - I've edited my question and added some background information.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use [NoPriv.py](https://raymii.org/s/software/Nopriv.py.html) to create an HTML archive of your inbox for viewing on Windows using a standard web browser.

### Screenshot of main page

[image: ss #1]

### Screenshot of Inbox

[image: ss #2]

Comment: Thanks - I will check this out. It may be exactly what is needed.